# Git pull not working even after untracking file?

Tags: git, github, gitignore, git-pull

My site uses an open source forum application with source code hosted on Github, and I have to update it using `git pull`.

The problem is I made some changes to a tracked file, so Git no longer allows me to do a `git pull` successfully. So, here's what I did to fix this:

- Added the file to .gitignore
- Ran the command `git update-index --assume-unchanged file.rb` to make sure that the file isn't tracked.

But I can't still do a `git pull` probably because of this -- even though the file is untracked locally, it's still tracked by the remote repository. In this case, how am I supposed to do a `git pull` to update my site, while making sure that `file.rb` is ignored?

**EDIT:** Please note that I can't make any changes to the remote repo. Any changes have to be made locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ignoring the file, try to commit it and then do the pull. If the file is not conflicting, it will be merged, otherwise you will be able to resolve conflicts locally using http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool, for example.

Comment: Correct, `git commit` does not make any remote changes, and after commiting you will be able to pull and merge remote changes

Comment: You mean, I have to run these commands, right? **1.** `git add .` **2.** `git commit -m 'Some changes'` **3.** `git pull` -- The git pull passed this time, but I hope this is the right way. Please let me know if I am doing it wrong.